# How to display row data as column in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to display row values as column values. and also display the final total value at end of the table.

To do that I'm using the below data set.

[image]

I want to set this data in the column side.

[image]

I used this SQL query to do that. But I don't know how to get Hours Total Column

```
select *   
from 
    (select EMP_NO,SUM(Hours) total
     from Employee_Attendence
     group by EMP_NO) 
pivot
    (sum(total) 
         for WAGE_Type in ('Absence', 'Normal'))
```

Final output should display as below.

```
Select EMP_NO, Absence, Normal, Total
From 
    (select *
     from 
         (select EMP_NO, sum(Hours) total
          from Employee_Attendence
          group by EMP_NO) 
     pivot
         (sum(total) 
              for WAGE_Type in ('Absence', 'Normal'))
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT emp_id, sum( CASE  WHEN wage_type = 'Absence' THEN Hours END ) Absence,
               sum( CASE  WHEN wage_type = 'Normal' THEN Hours END ) Normal,
               sum( hours ) "Hours total"
FROM employee_attendance
GROUP BY emp_id;
```

Output

```
EMP_ID  ABSENCE NORMAL HOURS TOTAL
4000    8       32     40
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot